# Configure Tor Browser to run over SSH SOCKS proxy?

Tags: ssh, proxy, socks, tor

I'd like to proxy all of my Tor Browser traffic through my home network remotely over SSH. If I have SSH access to a computer in my home network and a Tor Browser bundle here, how can I set up the tunnel and the browser to run remotely over a SOCKS tunnel?

Answer (score 1):

You can configure it so that it's:

```
you > tor network > ssh proxy server > internet
```

By using torsocks

```
torsocks ssh -D 8080 user@IP
```

I suppose you could configure it as you > proxy server > tor > internet, by having the traffic on your proxy server go through tor, but I'm not sure how, or even if it's possible.